# How to recover task function in gocron after server fails and reboots

Tags: go, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am using gocron to implement task scheduling. The following statement add a task to scheduler:

```
job, err := s.Every(5).Seconds().Do(func(){ ... })
```

The `func(){...}` is the task function to be executed. The project requires that, if the server fails and reboot, it can continue previous tasks.
I am thinking about using a database to store the task function information, but it's not a good solution since tasks might be different, and it's not easy to create a struct to store every type of task.
May I know some suggestions on recovering the task functions after rebooting? Thanks in advance.